# Visual Studio deletes all dll, pdb, xml files from Debug directory and requires publishing when I tried to publish application - how to restore them?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, publish

I am developing .NET 4.6.1 Console application with NuGet packages in with Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition and VS places all the NuGet-retrieved dll and compiled pdb, xml files in src/Debug directory. I guess that it is by default.

My project succesfully compiles, can be debugged and executed. But then I have tried to publish it. I received error message `Error An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\Debug\app.publish\MyApplication.exe. SignTool Error: Invalid option: /fd com.mycompany.myapplication` and I could see that all the dll, pdb and xml files are deleted from my Debug directory and new directory bin\Debug\app.publish has been created but with the exe file only.

So - after I tried to publish application 2 bad things happened:

1. dlls from NuGet packages have been delete, as a result I can not run my exe file any more;
2. And now the Visual Studio tries to publish application each time I am trying rebuild my project. And this publishing fails with `Failed to sign bin\Debug\app.publish\MyApplication.exe. SignTool Error: Invalid option: /fd com.mycompany.myapplication`, as a result I can not even rebuild my exe file.

How to decouple Rebuild from publishing and how not to do publishing during Rebuild time? And how to restore dlls from NuGet packages in my Debug directory? I.e. how to undo all the bad things that started to happen since I tried to publish application?

Answer (score 0):

I have followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/56739494/1375882 and executed 'Create Test Certificate...' with sha1RSA and after that both Publish and Rebuild happens as expected and even dll/pdb/xml files are restored automatically in my Debug directory. So, that solved the question, but maybe in suboptimal way...